# Handling errors during Paypal payment execution

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using PayPal REST API v1 for handling payments and from time to time I get errors during payment execution (`.../payments/PAY-XXXXXX/execute`). Specifically I have run into `TRANSACTION_REFUSED` and `PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID` so far. What is the correct way to handle them? Documentation isn't very extensive about these.

From what I understand, `TRANSACTION_REFUSED` means a problem with Payer account such as rejected card transaction or insufficient funds. In that case I display an erro message that PayPal has refused the transacation and  user should try again. Is this a way to go?

`PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID` is a mystery to me. I get that the payment should be in another state but how do I check if it has a correct state after creation? And how should I handle this error?

Thanks for any suggestions!

I'm using standard php sdk, version from 5. 5. 2014.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer to the `PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID` question. You can get the current status of the payment by fetching the "self" URL you initially got from the payment. That way, you can confirm the state of the payment, and maybe try and deduce why it's in the wrong state.

In my judgment, you should need to "handle" this error, since if you do the preceding steps correctly, the payment should always be in the correct state when you try to execute it.

As for the `TRANSACTION_REFUSED` question, I too would very much like to know.